# Cypress popup message - can NOT select ok or cancel

Tags: cypress-component-test-runner

I have a window that when I click on a button - there is a popup message it is written in Angular ,
I need to choose to confirm or cancel button at the popup window , but I can't reach the button
Via cypress
Can you please send me an example how to do it with cypress  ? (The popup window is written with Angular)
Thanks for your help ,
Ilanit .

I tried from other example to use the event - but didn't succeeded